# How to view console messages through Chrome DevTools Protocol?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket, google-chrome-devtools

I was able to get some error messages by sending `Log.enable`:

```
websocket.Send("{\"id\":1,\"method\":\"Log.enable\"}");
```

However, it does not give me all of the errors in the console or any of the messages sent via `console.log` in javascript.

How can I get an event for every console message using the Chrome DevTools Protocol?

Comment: See the documentation and examples for Log.entryAdded and Runtime.consoleAPICalled.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, I got it to start showing the events by using Runtime.enable